# Detect phones with "allphone" with goforward raw file

Tags: pocketsphinx

I've been experimenting with trying to get phonemes to be properly
detected.  I've been doing this with several of my own audio files and
had poor results.  Then I tried with the provided *goforward.raw* file
and it shows similar problematic results.

My install seems good, and it's working well for sentences:

```
% pocketsphinx_continuous -infile goforward.raw
go forward ten meters
```

But the `-allphone` option does not do what I expected.

```
% pocketsphinx_continuous -infile goforward.raw -allphone yes
SIL D SIL G OW F AO R W ER D JH T T EH N N M IY IH ZH ER Z S V SIL
```

It's not terrible, but there are some repeats and odd additions.  Are
there workarounds for this?  Is this a common result?  Do I need to
tweak some options or the raw file?

I ultimately only wish to process a single word input, so any tips for
accomplishing this are much appreciated.

System is Arch Linux with pocketsphinx 5prealpha.  I've tried this
with the source install and also the AUR package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command provided in [documentation](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/phonemerecognition/):

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -infile test/data/goforward.raw \
        -allphone model/en-us/en-us-phone.lm.bin \
        -beam 1e-20 -pbeam 1e-20 -lw 2.0
```

Comment: Thanks! That's much better. I still get "meezers" instead of "meters" but understand some caveats now. Hadn't found that documentation page.